# Github Cannot get commit count in badge

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I have a repository and I'm adding following badge to the readme.

```
[![GitHub commits](https://img.shields.io/github/commits-since/Naereen/StrapDown.js/v1.0.0.svg)](https://github.com/pawarashish564/AutoCompiler/commit/master)
```

> See this

[image: GitHub commits]

I changed the count url from my repository. Still it gets shows 45 . Total commits I have on my repository is 36. Please help me fix this.

thanks ✌️

Comment: You are displaying the information from the repository `Naereen/StrapDown.js`. I do not think, that this is what you want...

Comment: okay. I have tried this https://img.shields.io/badge/Commits-https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fpawarashish564%2FAutoCompiler%2Fcommits%2Fmaster-blue

Comment: I'm using https://shields.io/ to create this badges

Comment: Go to shields.io, enter commits in the search field and then, after selecting the badge you want, enter your information. shields.io generates the URL as you want it.

Comment: thanks that solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You referenced the wrong repository in your URL.

To get the right URL for your badge, it is best to use a wizard from [shields.io](https://shields.io) (e.g. for commits, since a version [this one](https://shields.io/category/activity)).

By entering your information (user name, repository, and tag, etc.), you can use the generated URL for your own badge.